# SpringCloudGateway from tanzu.vmware in kubernetes not working

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-gateway

I am following this guide from VMware docs:

"https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Spring-Cloud-Gateway-for-Kubernetes/2.0/scg-k8s/GUID-index.html"

I am able to deploy the gateway in my Kubernetes ([Guide](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Spring-Cloud-Gateway-for-Kubernetes/2.0/scg-k8s/GUID-guides-getting-started.html)), but when trying to port-forward to service/my-gateway I get a timeout:

```
$ kubectl port-forward service/my-gateway 8081:80
error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

In the [docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Spring-Cloud-Gateway-for-Kubernetes/2.0/scg-k8s/GUID-developer-troubleshooting.html) it says for logging I can use:

```
$ kubectl get springcloudgateway my-gateway
```

I get the result without READY or REASON filled just blank:

```
$ kubectl get springcloudgateway my-gateway
NAME               READY   REASON
my-gateway
```

Also it says I can enter the following:

```
$ kubectl logs statefulset.apps/my-gateway
```

But I don't have any gateway pods running.
So I am something wrong here but I don't know what?

gateway.yaml:

```
apiVersion: "tanzu.vmware.com/v1"
kind: SpringCloudGateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
```